# How to retrieve a single character from a QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qt4, textbox

I have the following character array:

```
char mychars[SIZE];
```

I would like to copy one character from a QTextEdit into that array.
I tried:

```
mychars[i] = this->ui->QTextEdit;
mychars[i] = this->ui->QTextEdit->inputContext();
```

But I get errors like:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘QTextEdit*’ to ‘char’
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with C++? It doesn't sound like you have the basic idea of data types and pointers. Or maybe read a bit about QTextEdit in Qt doc? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextedit.html

Comment: In agreement, you may be less frustrated after picking up a C++ book and familiarizing yourself with syntax and data types before using a framework like Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the text in your QTextEdit using:

```
QString text = this->ui->QTextEdit->toPlainText();
```

EDIT:

```
if(text.size()>0){
    mychars[0] = text[0].toAscii(); // assuming your text is ascii
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the [plain text](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop) back from the text edit using toPlainText().

To convert the `QString` to chars use something like

```
const QByteArray bytes = textEdit->toPlainText().toAscii();
const char*const characters = bytes.data();
```

For your specific case

```
mychars[i] = this->ui->QTextEdit->toPlainText().toAscii().data()[ i ];
```

should work.

Comment: mychars[i] = this->ui->QTextEdit->toPlainText(); => error: cannot convert ‘QString’ to ‘char’ in assignment

Answer (score 0):

You are currently attempting to insert the QTextEdit object into your character array and then something like the inputcontext of the text edit. You need to get the QString which constitutes the contents of the text edit select the index of the character you want and cast it to a char then insert it.

Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: In fact it's not even the QTextEdit itself it's just a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most methods in Qt use QString, so you want to read about them.
2. If you want to put 1 char into a char array, you have to specify which char you want, i.e. at which position the char is inside the string.

   mychars[i] = this->ui->textedit->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str()[0]